# LM2575 as Li-Ion charger

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, lithium-ion

I want to make a simple charger for my 2S1P battery. I found a lot of circuits using LDO regulators to get the typical CC/CV curve for Li-ion batteries like this:

[image]

but I wonder if it is possible to copy the 2N2222 circuit and use it in an adjustable SMPS regulator like LM2575-S for better efficiency. My idea is to use one of [this](https://github.com/megasaturnv/HX-2S-JH20-JH10-reverse-engineered_aka-2S-10A-Balance-Li-ion-Protection-PCB) BMS (between the charger and battery) to balance and protect the batteries. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the same kind of current-sensing based circuit is possible to be used, but it will be a bit harder to make it work, since the feedback loop of DC-DC converters is more finicky.

Also, while the DC-DC converter improves efficiency, note that you still are wasting a ton of energy in the current sense resistor (the 1Ω your schematic). If you charge at 1A, this is ~0.65V * 1A = 0.65W just for current sensing!

There are better ways to charge batteries using dedicated DC-DC converter chips which have a current sense input as well, ST's [L6902](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l6902.pdf) being one example. Just search for converters that also have current limiting built-in.